# Tiff image with bitmapsource, Slower than JPEG loading

Tags: wpf, windows-8.1, jpeg, .net-4.5, tiff

I have the below code in UI

```
 <ListBox x:Name="scannedImageslist" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxCustom}" Background="Gray"  SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding }"  ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                                    <!--<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true" >
                                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>-->
                                    <!--<ListBox.Resources>
                                        <gif:ImageConverter x:Key="UriToBitmapConverter" />
                                    </ListBox.Resources>-->
                                    <!--<ListBox.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1E2A2F" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </ListBox.Background>-->
                                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" >
                                            </WrapPanel>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <!--<Border BorderBrush="#FFFF9800" BorderThickness="3"  Width="120" Height="120" Padding="10" Margin="15" CornerRadius="10">-->
                                                <!--Bind Image Path in Image Control-->
                                                <!--<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="{Binding FullPath}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"></CheckBox>-->
                                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="True"  Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding FullPath}"  MouseRightButtonDown="Image_MouseRightButtonDown" >
                                                    <Image.Source>
                                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding FullPath}" DecodePixelWidth="200" CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" CacheOption="OnLoad"> </BitmapImage>
                                                   </Image.Source>
                                                    <Image.LayoutTransform>
                                                        <TransformGroup>
                                                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=sliderzoom,Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=sliderzoom,Path=Value}" />
                                                        </TransformGroup>
                                                    </Image.LayoutTransform>
                                                </Image>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ImageName}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Typography.SlashedZero="True"  Typography.NumeralStyle="OldStyle" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
```

Binding class and properties are

```
 public class ImageItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Properties
        public string FullPath { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public ImageItem(string fullPath)
        {
            FullPath = fullPath;
            //SetImage(fullPath);
            //Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@fullPath));
            ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
        }
  #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        #region Private Helpers
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

With the above code, the Jpegs are loading 10 times faster than Tiff images. Whats wrong with Tiff handling here and what would be correct approach in terms of performance?
Update:
I have used a converter and it is pretty fast just like Jpegs its loading Tiff, however the problem is not decode, the memory is eaten up.

```
public class UriConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {

       if (Path.GetExtension(value.ToString()).ToUpper() == ".TIF")
       {

           Stream tiff = new System.IO.FileStream(value.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
           TiffBitmapDecoder tiffdec = new TiffBitmapDecoder(tiff, BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
```

return tiffdec.Frames[0];
               //return tiffdec.Frames[0].Thumbnail;

```
           //GdPictureImaging obj = new GdPictureImaging();
           //int m_CurrentImage = obj.CreateGdPictureImageFromFile(value.ToString());
           //int thumnail= obj.CreateThumbnail(m_CurrentImage, 96, 96);

           //TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
           //MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
           //BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();
           //encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(tiffibitmapsource));
           //encoder.Save(memoryStream);
           //bImg.BeginInit();
           //bImg.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
           //bImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
           //bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
           //bImg.EndInit();
           //memoryStream.Close();

           //return bImg;

       }
       else
       {
           BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
           bi.BeginInit();
           bi.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
           bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
           bi.UriSource = new Uri(value.ToString());
           bi.EndInit();
           return bi;
       }

   }
   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

}

How to convert Bitmapsource to BitmapImage and then decode pixels!!!
TIFF doesnt have thumbnails, is there a way to create and store along, then display only thumbnail??

**Update 2**

As per MSDN

Is there a way TIF s to work as same as JPEG without conversion just for loading...

> The JPEG and Portable Network Graphics (PNG) codecs natively decode
>   the image to the specified size; other codecs decode the image at its
>   original size and scale the image to the desired size.

Comment: TIFF is a complicated format with many codecs, each codec will have a different performance level.  Why are you expecting JPEG and TIFF to take the same amount of time?  What codec are you using in your TIFF file?

Comment: I'm not using any codecs, as bitmapimage is able to handle it, there was nothing wrong in displaying thumnails and its working properly, however the cocern is performance. i'm expecting to handle CCITT.T6 compression tiff images

Comment: What if you remove the `DecodePixelWidth` setting from the BitmapImage and just set the `Width` of the Image control? According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth.aspx), only *the JPEG and Portable Network Graphics (PNG) codecs natively decode the image to the specified size; other codecs decode the image at its original size and scale the image to the desired size*.

Comment: There is a performance improvement, however the application memory is tremendously increased, that is why Decode pixels are been used here, there is an impact in other places like scrolling ans stuff.. This should be there

Comment: Then load the image in code behind (add a view mode property of type ImageSource) and [Freeze](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) it.

Comment: Still no luck, I have added the ImageSource property and binded the data, however the data loading performance remains same.. May be for tiff s I have to use alternate, any ideas

Comment: Update, If I use TiffBitmapdDecoder and then works like a charm however it is at the cost of memory. Can not possible to decode pixels of BitmspSource returned by codec.Frames[0] with high performance !!! is there any way?

Comment: I have used third party control and returned a stream with less size, even after loading taking ages, this could have been a issue drawing over the UI once the data is ready I believe !!! Any help appreciate