# WPF lack of image processing in particular decode Tiff

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image-processing, tiff

[MSDN Description about TIFF decode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The JPEG and Portable Network Graphics (PNG) codecs natively decode
>   the image to the specified size; other codecs decode the image at its
>   original size and scale the image to the desired size.According to the
>   above statement the TIFs are at its original size if we use
>   decodepixels.

Is there any workaround to improve the TIFs performance same as JPEGs.

Note: Its affecting the performance of loading hundreds of thumbnail images on a listbox, having said its able to handle Jpegs and pngs verywell.

Related question: [Tiff image with bitmapsource, Slower than JPEG loading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28267891/1834352).

Comment: Can you provide a sample image or at least provide more info about the images (bit-depth, compression, dimensions, colorspace, etc)?

Comment: black & white, 300 dpi, A4 size .. Basically it is a scanned image, no matter whatever the image color space the problem persists.. best thing to test is 300 dpi. as the dpi s are proportionate to processing speed.

Comment: You haven't specified the bit depth or compression type. A 8-bpp Flate compressed image will decode slower than a JPEG. A 1-bpp CCITT G4 image should decode very quickly.

Comment: bitdepth is 1 and CCITT T6 is the compression.

Comment: that compression and image size should decode extremely quickly. Only Microsoft could screw that up somehow. I don't use WPF, I wrote my own imaging code, so I can't directly help with this problem. JPEG thumbnails loading quickly is probably because there are EXIF thumbnails embedded in the files.

Comment: You are correct, JPEG s have thumbnail embedded, but for TIF it is null.. is there any way quickly creating thumbnail and attach to the image. I have used GDpicture component to create a thumbnail however its taking a while in a loop of hundreds to create thumbnail and stream that into ImageControl.

Comment: I could write something in native code to do it very quickly, but I'm not sure that would fit into your project. It is possible to specify a thumbnail image in a TIFF file, but like you said, you would need to pre-process all of the images. A better solution is to use more efficient code which can do it on the fly with any image you throw at it.